# How do I NOT use wayland?

Tags: xorg, wayland

The wayland window server in 22.04 seems rather fragile / not really ready for regular use.  Before the upgrade to 22.04, I was using the X11 server and it was rock solid.

Both chromium and chrome, and possibly other programs, cause wayland die fairly regularly, so I would like to avoid it until it is fixed.

Googling, I've seen suggestions to either select 'gnome on Xorg' at login time or to edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf to set WaylandEnable to false.  I've tried each of them and they are incomplete -- both result in a yellow screen with white text.  The text is unreadable even  if you put your eye an inch from the screen.

I'm tired of getting logged out multiple times a day due to the windowing server dying.

Suggestions?

David

Comment: " I've tried each of them and they are incomplete -- both result in a yellow screen with white text. " Then you have some other problem with your system, which you can ask about on this site. Logging in to an X session is the correct answer to the question you are asking here.

Comment: This sounds more like a color profile problem when you log in with X. Try logging in with X and then fiddle with your color profile settings if you can see to do so.

Comment: When I log in I can't read any text because of the low contrast between the text and the background.